# JavaScript console and QML WebView

Tags: javascript, debugging, webview, console, qml

Can I access some JavaScript console in QML? A page silently fails and I'd like to see the JavaScript errors.

I'm using QML WebView

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the below setting to the webview definition in the QML , then right click the webview , you should able to see "`Inspect`" button clicking on it should open the developer tools.

```
WebView {

............
............
............
settings.developerExtrasEnabled : true;

}
```

Comment: Just a notice for others that this is only accurate for Qt4 - it appears it's slightly more complicated for Qt5:  https://forum.qt.io/topic/36816/qt5-qml-qtwebkit-3-0-js-console/3